# SOFlair - An Android Widget that shows your Flair

Tags: app, android, widget

[image: SOFlair Screenshot]

Soflair is a (very) simple widget for Android that shows a user's flair (avatar, reputation & badges). The JSON is polled every 60 minutes.

#### Download

http://www-jo.se/f.pfleger/soflair

Comment: Just a quick note: the JSON flair method is deprecated and the API is (almost) just as simple to use, as it returns JSON data as well.

Comment: (: Yes, that's what I found out today. The app is now using the API.